# SQL: Find nth order for nth customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am quite new to SQL, have been learning for ~3 weeks, and have taken a liking to it. Hoping to polish up my skills before beginning to apply to Data Analyst roles.

I've been working with a dummy dvd-rental database and have found myself unable to solve a challenge given to me by a peer. The question was: "what is the most expensive rental for the 4th customer?"

[image]

We can see in picture, that based on the nth_customer column, Terrance Roush is the 4th ever customer (he's the 4th ever person to pay). But the issue is that the nth_customer column is actually reporting back the nth order and continues counting to infinity. So the next time Terrance shows up, the nth_customer column will not show '4' (which is what I was hoping to achieve).

Would appreciate any feedback on how to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please _delete_ that external image link and instead include the sample data directly in your question as _text_.  Then, add aliases to everything in the select clause.  We can't figure out which column belongs to which table.

Comment: What if there are 2 customers who are both 4th ever people to pay?

Comment: The problem here seems to be your definition of the "nth customer". Your rank over column nth_customer reports the rank of all customers ever. So if a customer pays 2 orders in a row he will have two different nth_customer values. To solve this problem you need to get only the lowest of those values. So you need to make another CTE where you will GROUP BY customer_id and take the MIN(nth_customer). This will give you the "real nth_customer".

Comment: Please do **not** post code or sample data as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: One concept you need to get firmly established in your mind: **There is no such thing as nth row**,  from any table and by extension any query.  Tables are by definition *unordered tuples* (rows),  order is established only with an ORDER BY clause.  Since your window function partitions by customer_id but orders only by payment_date there is no guarantee customers appear in the same order each time the query runs, if multiple customers have the same payment_date. Yes, rare at same microsecond but not so rare as one would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "the fourth customer" means the customer who did the fourth rental, you can break the problem down into two - finding that fourth customer, and finding their most expensive rental. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM payment 
WHERE customer_id = (
    SELECT customer_id 
    FROM payment 
    ORDER BY payment_date 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
) 
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here I'm finding the ID of the fourth customer in the subquery, using a LIMIT & OFFSET to get just the one record I want. Then in the outer query I'm simply ordering all of that customer's records and taking the one with the biggest amount.